# Python - program written in Python 3.5.2 also executable on higher python versions?

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.5, python-3.6

I've written a program on the python version 3.5.2, because i need a 64 bit version of python for my tensorflow-gpu library.

Its also possible to use the normal tensorflow library, which doese'nt require a 64 bit python, but in my case i wanted to use my gpu.

My question is: If some users have a higher version installed (of python) and use the normal tensorflow library, will they still be able to execute it?

Fabian

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Also, if you need to make sure of the version, install multiple versions of python, such as 2.7, 3.2, and later versions. This will allow you to make multiple scripts, for different versions.                           Such as: Py27.py ; Py32.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what code you used, and if the syntax was changed in later versions. For example, if your version of Python uses `print "Hello World!"` and the user's version is `print("Hello World")`, then you would have to change it to the later versions specification.